# Is possible to save UIWebView with NSUserDefault?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I'm making a rss reader. I'm implementing a 'Download' button: when I click download I want the page I see at that time in the UIWebView to be saved locally. When the user opens the application again (even if there is no connection), he must be able to read the previously saved web page.

Can you give me help or advice?

I was thinking of saving the whole UIWebView in NSUserDefault..I do not know ..

Answer (score 0):

You can get current HTML from your UIWebView and save in NSUserDefault as string. And receive this page from NSUserDefault when will be needed.

```
//geting html
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                     @"document.body.innerHTML"]

//load html
[yourWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Or you can store HTML page in file (this will be better)

Comment: That's all ?? So simple?

Comment: And css? Image?

Comment: There was a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45172376/1305067) I responded to a short time ago. This is called an offline cache, and there is a tutorial here: http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol. This will take care of all assets such as JavaScript, images, CSS and any other resources the page uses.